# find the conditions that guarantee the different equations have same solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$\begin{aligned}
& \boldsymbol{A}_{n\times m},\boldsymbol{B}_{m\times n},\boldsymbol{AB}=\boldsymbol{C}
\end{aligned},$
find the condition that let 
$\begin{aligned}
& \boldsymbol{Cx}=\boldsymbol{0},
\end{aligned}$
and 
$\begin{aligned}
& \boldsymbol{Bx}=\boldsymbol{0},
\end{aligned}$
have same solution.

this question was extracted from my exercise book,the answer  use the conclusion directly , but I'm not clear about the theory.

in the oringinal question, the condition is $\begin{aligned}
& \boldsymbol{A}_{n\times m},\boldsymbol{B}_{m\times n},n>m,\boldsymbol{AB}=\boldsymbol{E}
\end{aligned},$
and the answer says $\begin{aligned}
& \boldsymbol{Cx}=\boldsymbol{0},
\end{aligned}$
and 
$\begin{aligned}
& \boldsymbol{Bx}=\boldsymbol{0},
\end{aligned}$
have same solution without further explanation.

Comment: It is clear that if $Bx =0$ then $ABx=0$, hence $\ker B \subset \ker (AB)$. Under what conditions on $A$ can you guarantee that if $ABx=0$ then $Bx = 0$ for any $x$?

Comment: @copper.hat r(AB)=r(B)?

Comment: That would be a sufficient condition, but is not necessary. How must $A$ behave on ${\cal R} B$?